# time complexity solving method

Tags: c, time-complexity

any easy method to calculate time complexity but not using searching and sorting
for eg: An array of size n initialized with 0.
write a code which inserts the
value 3k at position 3k in the array, whe re k=0,1…

Comment: can you clarify your question please?

Comment: result: `O(n)` because you need `n/3` operations to fill every third cell in an array of size n

Answer (score 0):

Can you make this a bit more clear?
The way I am understanding this right now, are you asking how I could for example given the array 
    [1 2 2 1 4 5 6 3 2 4 ...] 
multiply the value at k by 3?
If that is so, that would be a matter of indexing into the array.

If you are trying to find the value 3 in the array, there are multiple ways to go about it.
You could simply traverse the array, which is going to be at most o(n) time, but if it is sorted, just do a binary search.

edit:
By time complexity, the first one would be o(1) and the binary search would 
be o(log n)

Comment: OP talks about inserting some values in an array initialized to 0